# Insert Data from one Mysql table in Server A to Another Mysql Table inside SSIS

Tags: mysql, ssis

I'm trying to insert some id from MySQL Table `T1` in Server A, into MySQL Table `T2` in Server B  inside an SSIS package.

I've tried ADO.NET source for reading data and ADO.NET destination and it gives me this error:

> [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ADONETDestination.PreExecute()
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: ADO NET Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004003.

Actually, I've solved the problem by inserting into a SQL Server table and then run the `Insert` statement through a linked server with this statement:

```sql
EXEC(@Insert) AT [LinkedServerName]
```

I wonder if there is a better solution?

Comment: SQL server component can hardly access a mysql server. Do you have mysql connector/net or myodbc installed?

Comment: @Shadow quite the opposite - SSIS uses OLEDB, ODBC and ADO.NET connectors that can connect to almost every available data source, as long as the appropriate provider is installed

Comment: How did you configure that destination? Which ADO.NET provider are you using? Which version? Oracle's Connector/NET is a bit temperamental, so people typically use other providers. If you use Connector/NET, have you upgraded to the latest version> Have you considered using the ODBC driver instead?

Comment: we are using .net provider\MYSQL data provider

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install MySQL ODBC connector to the machine where SSIS is running first. You can download it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). Then you can create ODBC connection to MySQL in SSIS and use ODBC data source and destination. You will have to specify installed connector in the "Driver" property of ODBC connection.

Comment: ,We have install {MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver} and we have no problem with data source component. the problem is with destination

Comment: sorry we are using .net provider\MYSQL data provider

Comment: can you try to load using either ODBC or OLEDB destiations? You will have to install ODBC driver for that, but based on my experience you can sometimes get more meaningful SSIS error messages from these providers. So even if it will not work, it might show you "better" error message